# Sheet popping out of a view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

is it possible to have a sheet that pops out of a view? For example, I'd like to make it pop out of a bottom view in a `NSSplitView`.

I'm aware of popovers on Lion, but I need sheets since they are modal, they are available before Lion, and they are harder to dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's not possible and also not in line with Apple's UI guidelines. Obviously you could try to roll your own but that would involve a considerable amount of work.

EDIT: Actually, I think rolling your own is also difficult. The tools at hand are either a view or a window. I think you cannot use a view as views cannot draw themselves outside the frame of a window - unless you can somehow restrain your dialog within the bounds of the window that shows them. You would then need to setup the animation that shows the rolling sheet from your NSSplitView.

Windows are then the other alternative. To have them behave like modal sheets, you would want them borderless and by design they then cannot become a key window. So, the user would need to explicitly click the sheet to get focus which defies the purpose of a modal sheet in my opinion.

Both ways, a challenge...